# what will be the answer of this limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n} x =?$

The given answer is $0$. I tried solving  it by using the fact that $0 \le \cos^2 x \le 1$, after this I am unable to solve further. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Try using the fact that, if $0 < a < 1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a^n = 0$.

Comment: If $x = n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, it would seem the limit is $1$, as the sequence would be constant.

Comment: Does the question specify anything about the value of $x$?

Comment: @2012ssohn I don't know how that helps? Just like NicholasStull said...

Comment: If we plot $\cos^{2n} x$ for very high $n$, we'll see that the entire function is (approximately) $0$ with the exception, as @NicholasStull mentioned, when $x = n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Letting $g(x)$ be a function such that $g(x) = 1$ when $x = n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise, we can see that, although $g(\pi) = 1$, the LIMIT is $0$ (i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi} g(x) = 0$).

Comment: @2012ssohn That being the case, we don't (without proving further properties of the sequence) have a limit which is identically equal to $0$ (or even continuous).  We currently have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x=n\pi\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{Z}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
but unless we were able to prove that $\cos^{2n}(x)$ converges uniformly as $n\to\infty$ (which seems doubtful at best), then there is no reason to believe the limit would be a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(x) \, \bigg |_{x \not\equiv 0 \mod \pi  } = 0 $

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(x) \, \bigg |_{x \equiv 0 \mod \pi  } =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^{2n} = 1 $

Since the value of the limit depends on the independent variable, the limit does not exist:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(x) = \text{undef} $